# Firebase functions emulator does not watch for changes

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-tools

#### Environment info

`firebase --version` --> `11.1.0`

`node -v` --> `v16.15.1`

`npm -v` --> `8.11.0`

**Platform:**

Pop!_OS 22.04 LTS 64-bit

#### Steps to reproduce

1). run `firebase init functions`

2). Select `Use an existing project` and choose my project.

3). Select `Javascript` for the language.

4). Type `N` and press enter to not use eslint.

5). Type `Y` and press enter to install dependencies.

6). run `firebase emulators:start` or `firebase emulators:start --only functions`

7). Open `functions/index.js` and uncomment the helloWorld example, and save.

#### Expected behavior

I expect the functions emulator to detect the changes to the javascript code and to automatically apply those changes without restarting the emulator (manually).

#### Actual behavior

Nothing changes. I have to restart the emulator to use the helloWorld function. Or if the function was there when the emulator was started I have to restart it to see changes made to the function itself. If I make changes to the `firestore.rules` file while running the firestore emulator those changes are registered without restarting the emulator(s) like it's supposed to.

Comment: Please someone tell me if I'm being an idiot. When I start the emulator it says functions: Watching \"path\" for Cloud Functions... Does this not mean what I think it means? If so how to I update functions without restarting every emulator I have running?

Comment: Searching for a solution with NestJS also

Answer (score 2):

If you're using "native" Node.js, any changes/modification in the code after running the emulator will not be reflected. By using different Javascript library, you can transpile/compile your code as watch mode before running Firebase emulator to see the changes upon modification of the code. You can also refer to this [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/local-emulator#:%7E:text=Note%3A%20Code,as%20you%20save.):

> Code changes you make during an active session are automatically
> reloaded by the emulator. If your code needs to be transpiled
> (TypeScript, React) make sure to do so before running the emulator.
> You can run your transpiler in watch mode with commands like tsc -w to
> transpile and reload code automatically as you save.

Comment: I'm not using "native" Node.js or typescript. It isn't automatically updating. I have to fully restart all emulators to see the changes.

Comment: If you think that there is a bug in the emulator while reproduction steps, post the project GitHub instead of Stack Overflow. [GitHub](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools)